# Rules for Early Migration

Tags: history

So far, I have created a natural world,  and I'm starting to think about putting a history of human interactions in it. First I'm going to start with the early history. That includes early migration, which lays down the foundation of future history, but I don't know how to structure it properly. Here is an example of what I want it to look like.[image]

Here is mine.

[image]

The base question is:

How do I structure the migration paths?

1:Do I make them go everywhere that they can get to?

2:Make them walk forever until they find a good area?

3:Force then to split up every once in a while?

Comment: Extra information would be nice, but not needed.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by "What are humans attracted to?" Humans will expand into all regions that they have the technology to inhabit or access.

Comment: I meant geological features like rivers, mountains, islands etc. sorry

Comment: Ohh, so: "Where do humans tend to settle?"

Comment: Hi Ender, please make sure to limit your questions down to 1 question per post and also don't make them completely open ended. This usually makes them far too broad because there are often too many considerations to take into account. A standard rule for human migration is this: If there isn't enough food, a group splits or migrates. The group will settle somewhere where they can gather enough food. Water is a good source because it supplies both water and food and there is no need to wait for the food (fish) to grow and be harvested

Comment: Are you sure you've uploaded the correct img?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1: Where do I start my first group?

Anywhere that is primitive civilization friendly

> 2: When do I stop a group?

Usually, never. Somebody stops off at each point along the way while some subset goes farther. Near the end you have what is called a serial founder effect. Sometimes groups merge too.

> 3: When do I branch off?

Every time that primitive people can while still having access to fresh water and habitable temperatures.

> 4: What geological features do humans tend to settle in?

Fresh water and habitable temperatures are key. Many early migrations inland followed rivers from a coast to their source. Even a few miles of water, e.g., to a new island or continent is a very strong barrier. Jungles, deserts, ice fields, glaciers, tundra, areas inhabited by rivals (human or otherwise), and mountains can also be strong barriers and at least channel people into narrow routes between them or along rivers that run through them.

Also, climate and sea level are not constant and the course of rivers can change. What is passable at one time may not be passable at another. When conditions get bad in an area, everyone who tries to stay there dies.

Comment: Pretty neat, +1. You should have mentioned food along with water, though. For example, people used to fishing on the coast will follow the coast and sub-groups will branch off for other food sources such as fishing on rivers or lakes. You can see this in the above map with separate arrows inland and coastal arrows for settling North America. This is because coastal people primarily fished and followed the coast while the inland people primarily hunted and followed their prey. Similarly people with specific form of agriculture will migrate based on suitability for that. Which depends on tech.

Comment: Where there is water and habitable temperatures, there is also almost always food.

Comment: Yes, but the type of food supply is also relevant.

Answer (score 2):

> What geological features do humans tend to settle in?

Some place with food and water. The places with the easiest food, the cleanest water and nicest weather will be settled first.

> When do I branch off?

Any time that one group gets too big. There is a premise that due to our brain size, the [largest size group of people](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Dunbar%27s_Number) (where you can know everyone, or where shame is effective for control) [is about 150](http://www.cracked.com/article_14990_what-monkeysphere.html). Many communal groups (such as [Hutterites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hutterites) and Mennonites) tend to split into 2 when their group/church size gets above 150-200 (the Hutterites moved a lot over the 400-ish years their denomination has existed).

A group that gets too large for the local terrain to support will have to break apart eventually. I don't think that logistics (shipping goods over a distance) is a *thing* at this time in your world.

Or that they'd like to settle someplace nice, but it is already occupied. Or worse, a stronger bunch decided to move in and kick your lot out.

> When do I stop a group?

Hey, this place looks nice! Or, this place looks nice but there are bums we need to kick out!

Comment: Note that the largest size group of people is not dependent on the most social people in the group knowing everybody. It's closer to the average person knowing everyone, but it's possible you'd want to take it farther than that. 90% of everyone knows everyone? Basically, unless you're a shut-in, you know most people by the time you're an adult, and probably a lot sooner.

Comment: "this place looks nice but there are bums we need to kick out!" In human prehistory during the hunter-gather era, this almost never happened. Places with existing Neanderthal or human populations were avoided by migrants. Only with farming and herding did this start to happen.

Comment: they were ALL bums